# Verificar se lista é igual

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
x = [([1,2], [1, 2]), ([1,2], [4, 5])]
```

E queria verificar se a primeira lista de cada tuplo é sempre igual.

Nota: a lista x contém tuplos com listas. Esses tuplos podem variar, ou seja, podem haver mais tuplos com outros valores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu usaria o método **[all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)** do Python fazendo um for nas tuplas.

Exemplo:

```
a = [([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 2], [4, 5])] # primeira lista igual
b = [([1, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 3], [4, 5])] # primeira lista diferente
c = [([1, 2], [2, 2]), ([1, 2], [4, 5]), ([1, 2], [4, 2]), ([1, 2], [1, 6]), ([1, 2], [6, 3])]
d = [([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 2]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 6]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 3])]

all([y == x[0] for y in [x[0] for x in a]])
True

all([y == x[0] for y in [x[0] for x in b]])
False

all([y == x[0] for y in [x[0] for x in c]])
True

all([y == x[0] for y in [x[0] for x in d]])
True
```

Comment: e se a lista tiver mais tuplos?? porque o numero de tuplos é indeterminado..

Comment: @StinRose , não importa a quantidade nem de itens na primeira lista, nem de listas dentro da tupla. 

A resposta está atualizada com mais exemplos.

Comment: mas neste caso eu nao vou ter 2 listas para comparar se são diferentes ou nao... eu no codigo tenho uma função em que peço essa lista, e eu preciso de testar se o que eles me deram está de acordo com o pedido... neste caso tem de ter a primeira lista de cada tuplo sempre igual

Comment: É exatamente o que esse código faz. Ele pega todos as primeiras listas das tuplas e verifica se são iguais. Se alguma não for igual ele retorna False

Comment: ah pois, tem razão! obrigada!